# fullpage.js adding 2 autoscroll events between section

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

Is it possible to add auto-scrolling events before the section scroll to the next portion? Let's say after scrolling to section 2, the user must scroll twice, which will activate two separate animations, before then scrolling to section 3. Should I disable the auto scroll? I have tried to use this

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                if(index == 2 && direction =='down'){
                    function act2s(){

                        $('.sc1').removeClass('opno').delay(1000).promise().done(function(){
                            $('.sc2').removeClass('opno').delay(500).promise().done(function(){
                                $('.vg_act2-inner').addClass('vertical_grid_active');
                                $('.hg_act2-anti_inner').addClass('horizontal_grid_active');
                                $('.hg_act2-anti_out-inner').addClass('hg_act2-anti_out-inner_active');
                                $('.hg_act2-inner').addClass('hg_act2-inner_active').delay(500).promise().done(function(){
                                    $('.red2').addClass('red_active');
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    setTimeout(act2s, 2000);
                    return false;
                }
            },
```

However, some strange reason the animation is stopped just after the first sc1 has the class removed. Is there a way to catch the two scroll events to activate the animation and then returning true again so the section can resume sliding?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#cancelling-the-scroll-before-it-takes-place)

> **Cancelling the scroll before it takes place**
>
> You can cancel the scroll by returning false on the onLeave callback:

```
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
            //it won't scroll if the destination is the 3rd section
            if(nextIndex == 3){
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```